# OpenERP: Use field value in attribute of html tag in form view

Tags: html, odoo

is it possible to use a field from the model as attribute inside an html tag.

Specifically in a form view I would like to create a link to an external issue tracker from the issue number taken from my model. I would like to display the issue number as link text with the full URL as external target.

Like that:

`<a href="www.example.com" target="_blank"><field name="issue_nr" nolabel="1"/></a>`

This is working nicely so far as I get a link to the URL displayed with the issue number as label and in edit mode I get a text field where I can change the issue number itself.

My problem is that I don't know how to set the href attribute dynamically. The idea would be to get the link build by a dynamic field. I tried this and it is working well, but I don't know how to get the content of that dynamic field inside the href attribute of the anchor.

Any ideas? I don't necessarily need a field for href. If it's possible to do this with python code, that would be fine too.

Thanks and regards,

Peter

Answer (score -1):

I suggest adding a functional field in your model in python:

```
def _generate_href(self, cr, uid, ids, field, arg, context=None):
    res = {}

    for id in ids:
        issue = self.browse(cr, uid, id)
        res[id] = "http://example.com/" + str(issue.issue_nr)

    return res

_columns = {
    #...
    href_link: fields.function(_generate_href, type="char", size=128, string='Web address')
    #...
}
```

And then in your view you can do this:

```
<field name="href_link" nolabel="1" widget="url" readonly="1"/>
```

Comment: That is what I already tried, but 1.) widget="url" seams to do nothing in tree views and 2.) this doesn't solve the problem of generating a link with different link text target url.

Comment: I just found this app for version 7: [web_url](https://www.odoo.com/apps/7.0/web_url/). There is one for version 6.1 too. This could solve problem 1)